# Paypal Express Checkout cancellation

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am setting up a payment system using Paypal's Express Checkout. When the user submits their payment, and then confirms on Paypal, they are redirected to our website. On our website, there is a button that says "Confirm Payment" and submits the information to our database.

My question is, am I required to have a cancel button on my website? If I am required to have this cancel button, what should I have the button tell Paypal when it cancels? Do I need to tell Paypal that the token is no longer valid, or do I only need to tell my website that the payment is cancelled?

Edit: Found the answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522835/how-do-i-cancel-a-paypal-express-checkout-transaction)

Comment: Do you want to ask this of random people on the web?  Why not ask Paypal?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's a vendor support question, and should be addressed to PayPal. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of questions that are proper to ask here; you might want to take a few minutes to review it. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i cancel a PayPal (Express Checkout) transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522835/how-do-i-cancel-a-paypal-express-checkout-transaction)